# Create .master file without creating .html file in Teamsite in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am working on teamsite that has Publish features enabled.

1. Is it necessary to have a .html file and then generate .master file out of it to be used for both publishing pages and site pages.
2. How to upload Starter PubCollab master file in the referenced link below. Does it need to be uploaded as HTML master page or ASP.NET master page.

https://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/releases/view/97062

3. Does ASP.NET master page is only for publishing pages but not for site pages?
4. I would like to have only .master file that can be applied to both publishing and site pages. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Master Pages should be stored in `_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx` It doesn't matter what content type you pick really, SharePoint does not enforce these content types when you are assigning the masterpage to a site, but using the correct one for the type of masterpage you are using is clearly the best choice.

As far as HTML vs ASP.NET, I have always done masterpages in ASP based on the default masterpages provided by Microsoft (v4.master, v5.master) since you know they best support all OOTB functionality and won't have any issues.  ASP.NET works fine on all types of SharePoint pages and should look the same for Publishing, Team and System pages including settings pages.  This has been true since 2010.  I have always deployed my branding solutions via Solution WSP files, but that's not necessary either.

So to answer your last question, yes, yes you can.  It's how I have always setup my site collections.